# How to hide the register address in a class

Tags: c++, driver, cpu-registers

I am creating a driver and I have declared my registers like this in the header file of my class.

```
private:

static const uint32_t REG1 = (0x00000000);
static const uint32_t REG2 = (0x00000004);
static const uint32_t REG3 = (0x00000008);
static const uint32_t REG4 = (0x0000000c);
static const uint32_t REG5 = (0x00000010);
// etc ...
```

Then in my `.cpp`, I have done this:

```
const uint32_t Class::REG1;
const uint32_t Class::REG2;
const uint32_t Class::REG3;
const uint32_t Class::REG4;
const uint32_t Class::REG5;
```

I have been told that I need to hide the register values and don't put them into the header.  Which is the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: Are these addresses only used by your own class or by other compilation units as well?  Could you maybe extend your example to a compileable class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to put them in an *anonymous namespace* in the source file for the class, dropping them from the header (and the class) entirely:

```
namespace /*no name mean it's an anonymous namespace*/ {
    const uint32_t REG1 = ( 0x00000000);
    /*etc*/
}
```

I've dropped the `static` as well as it's no longer necessary.

That way, they will only be accessible from that particular compilation unit.

Comment: I used the static as I did not want every object to make its own variables.  I guess now each object will?

Comment: How will an object end up with a copy of something that is not even declared inside the object's class?

Comment: @5gon12eder I believe that's where OP is confused about Bathsheba's answer

Comment: So, they're in the global space and created when the first object is and destroyed when the app terminates?

Comment: They have static storage duration and are initialized upon program startup and deinitialized at program exit.  But since they are just plain old integers, the compiler will simply put their value in the constant data section of the executable and the values will just be there.  If you never take their address, the compiler might even elide them all together and substitute the value whenever the variable is used.  They are *not* in the global namespace because put inside an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can always initialize constants in the implementation source.

Header :

```
private:

    static const uint32_t REG1;
    static const uint32_t REG2;
    static const uint32_t REG3;
    static const uint32_t REG4;
    static const uint32_t REG5;
```

Implementation cpp :

```
const uint32_t Class::REG1 = (0x00000000);
const uint32_t Class::REG2 = (0x00000004);
const uint32_t Class::REG3 = (0x00000008);
const uint32_t Class::REG4 = (0x0000000c);
const uint32_t Class::REG5 = (0x00000010);
```

This way the constants are still static member of the class, and the value is in the implementation part. That way, you can still use them without defining the value in header event if the class implementation is separated in several compilation units.